# Facet Search with Solr

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am a newbie and learning facet search with the Solr library. I want to generate a tag cloud using the above for my project. Can anyone please give an example as to how it can be done  along with its basic setup?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the field you want to generate a cloud for is named `myField` and that you want a cloud with a maximum of 50 tags, this could be your search:

```
q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=myField&rows=0&facet.limit=50
```

This will give you a query response with no rows but with a "facet counts" section. Then you can use those term counts to determine the font size of every tag (probably in a logarithmic fashion).

Keep in mind that your field should include a [whitespace tokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Tokenizers) and should not be too heavily "processed" with analyzers (e.g. stemming) at index time, or your facet terms might not be as you expect. If that is the case, use [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) to get your content indexed in a less processed field.

You've got a whole bunch of other faceting options available to tune your tag cloud: [SimpleFacetParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters).